# Adding Different Autocompletes of JQuery UI to Dynamically created Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Update 1 I need to add the auto completes to the newly created clones.

```
   $('input[name^="numEmp"]').autocomplete({

    source: Empleados,select: function(event, ui) {$(this).val(ui.item.value);return false;}});         

$('input[name^="servicioNom"]').autocomplete({

    source: Servicios,select: function(event, ui) {$(this).val(ui.item.value);return false;}});




   $(".Nuevo").on("click", function() {
   $(".readdireccion:last").clone().insertAfter(".readdireccion:last").

   find('.emp').autocomplete({
   source: Empleados,select: function(event, ui) {$(this).val(ui.item.value);}}).

   find('input[name^="servicioNom"]').autocomplete({
   source: Servicios,select: function(event, ui) {$(this).val(ui.item.value);}});   



});
```

cant seem to get them in there

UPDATE 2!FINALLY WORKING HUGE THANKS TO SALMAN A !!

```
   $('input[name^="numEmp"]').autocomplete({

    source: Empleados,select: function(event, ui) {$(this).val(ui.item.value);return false;}});         

$('input[name^="servicioNom"]').autocomplete({

    source: Servicios,select: function(event, ui) {$(this).val(ui.item.value);return false;}});




   $(".Nuevo").on("click", function() {
   $(".readdireccion:last").clone().insertAfter(".readdireccion:last")

   $('input[name^="numEmp"]').autocomplete({

    source: Empleados,select: function(event, ui) {$(this).val(ui.item.value);return false;}});         

$('input[name^="servicioNom"]').autocomplete({

    source: Servicios,select: function(event, ui) {$(this).val(ui.item.value);return false;}});


});
```

hope this helps anyone in with these problems

Comment: Cloning that results in duplicate IDs will produce unexpected results.

Comment: so do you think that the duplicate id's are producing the problem for the autocomplete??

Comment: In most browsers, if there are multiple `#Foo` elements, `$("#Foo")` selects only the first one.

Comment: not quite sure what your saying... how would I work around this ? not lazy or anything but having trouble and this was my last resort.

Comment: been at this for the past 2 days :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/SzMWk/7/). In your case, it is best that you do not use vanilla JavaScript to clone elements. Use [`jQuery.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to clone your elements; and call [`.autocomplete()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) on the newly created elements. Also as suggested in my comment, do not clone elements that have (or contain elements with) ID attribute. Duplicate ID elements are not good.

Comment: Thanks! im starting to get somewhere however, in the fiddle you sent me you can only delete it once after that it ignores the instruction

Comment: try changing `.clone()` to `.clone(true)`

Comment: I did but now the autocompletes for the new elements are somehow linked to the first one.

Comment: also im not sure if it works for you but the newly generated field must be blank

Comment: sorry maybe im not specifying well enough 
 when I click on the button add employee I want a new element with its own autocomplete now from the code you gave me I managed to assign each one to mine but im not sure how to add because I am using this inside the autocomplete where numEmp is the employee Id I want to get filled in the input     
              




    select: function(event, ui) {        
    $("#numEmp")[0].val(ui.item.value);
    $("#numEmp")[0].val(ui.item.desc);
    return false;

Comment: I am afraid you need to improvise yourself.

Comment: hmmmm so do u know of an alternate path?

Comment: because I doubt that it would work the first way even if I assign ID's correctly

Comment: DUDE!! I GOT IT!! Just lend me your mind one more time :) how can I set the newly cloned div to ""

Comment: save a reference to the cloned div in a variable e.g. `var $clone = $(".readdireccion:last").clone().insertAfter(".readdireccion:last");`... then do the operations e.g. `$clone.find("input,select").val("");`

Comment: nope did not work with the autocomplete parts but im so close there has to be a way :-)

Comment: Edit the fiddle I posted and enter whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: Got it Salman A thanks bro could not have done it with out your help